# Editing facet headings on a Plotly chart

Tags: pandas, plotly

So I want to customise my chart axes titles

So my graphs are printing out the correct data but for one of the graphs the axis does not match the hover text.

```
df["M "] = df["Date_Modified"]
fig = px.bar(df, x = "M ", y = "Count", facet_row = "Entity",     color = "Entity") 
fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0, opacity=1)
fig.update_layout(title=(option.title() + " by company"), yaxis_zeroline=False, xaxis_zeroline=False)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text = "")
    fig.show()
```

[image]

So I want to get rid of the entity axis and also make the count be only displayed once

[image]

I want the Facet title for the second image be more clean so just Feb19 or Mar 19 and not with an = sign

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE: as of `plotly` version 4.2 in October 2019, the following usage of `for_each_annotation` is recommended by the docs at https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/#customize-subplot-figure-titles

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(px.data.tips(), x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_row="sex")

fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))

fig.show()
```

---

The facet titles here are stored as annotations in the figure, under `fig.layout.annotations` so you can edit them directly in there with e.g. `fig.layout.annotations[0].text = "new text"`

Here's a simple loop to just keep the part after the `=` sign:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(px.data.tips(), x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_row="sex")

for annotation in fig.layout.annotations:
    annotation.text = annotation.text.split("=")[1]

fig.show()
```